# Scala Play 2.4 how to test action composition (using action builder and action filter)

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I have written an action builder and apply this new action to my controller with Injection.

Below is my code:

```
class AuthAction @Inject()(authService: AuthService) {
    def AuthAction(userId: Int) = new ActionBuilder[Request] with ActionFilter[Request] {
        def filter[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Option[Result]] = {
            request.headers.get("Authorization").map(header => {
                authService.isAuth(header).flatMap {
                    case true => Future.successfuly(None)
                    case false => Future.successfuly(Some(Forbidden))
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

class UserController @Inject()(auth: AuthAction, xxxService: XxxService) extends Controller {
    def xxx(userId: Int) = auth.AuthAction(userId).async { implicit request =>
        xxxService.xxx().map.......
    }
}
```

Without using customised action, I can easily test UserController with ScalaTest and Mockito (Fake request and mock xxxService)

My question is how can I mock AuthAction and test UserController using ScalaTest and Mockito?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about what sort of value to inject into the `UserController` in the tests?

Comment: No, I am asking how can i unit test my controller and how to mock the injected value?